# Full Calendar refetchResources not woking in version 5.5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
            refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true,
            customButtons: {
                myCustomButton: {
                    text: 'Filter',
                    click: function() {}
                }
            },
            viewClassNames: function(info) {
                calendarEl.querySelectorAll('.fc-button').forEach((button) => {
                    if (button.innerText === 'Filter') {
                        button.classList.add('custom-btn')
                    }
                });
            },
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            //themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
            aspectRatio: 1.5,
            headerToolbar: {
                right: 'myCustomButton,prev,today,next',
                center: 'title',
                left: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineYear'
            },
            editable: true,
            resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Vehicles',
            resources: <?= globalfunctions::vehicles_reources(); ?>,
        });
        calendar.render();
        $("#group").change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == '1') {
                resources = <?= globalfunctions::vehicles_reources(); ?>;
            } else {
                resources = <?= globalfunctions::operator_resources(); ?>;
            }
            calendar.refetchResources();
        });
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var d = new Date(dateText);
                calendar.gotoDate(d)
            }
        });
    });
```

On chaning dropdown needed to fetch different resources. Calendar resources are not refetched after event change. Please provide example to refetch the event on change of dorpdown. I am using fullcalendar 5.5.1.

Comment: What does `globalfunctions::vehicles_reources();` return? If it just returns a list of objects then no, refetchResources won't do anything because fullCalendar has no way of knowing where to fetch updated data from - it can't execute your server-side code directly. For re-fetching to work, you need to supply the "resources" option as either a URL or a function which fullCalendar can use to go and get new resource data. If you consider it logically, it becomes obvious to see that it can't refresh a hard-coded list of objects!

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-function for info on the ways to supply the resources as a re-fetchable feed rather than a static list.

Comment: @ADyson globalfunctions::vehicles_reources(); returns json object. If a put put resource URL it works. Thanks for helping me out.